# Reading CSV data in Spring Batch (creating a custom LineMapper)

Tags: java, csv, spring-batch

I've been doing a bit of work writing some batch processing code on CSV data. I found a tutorial online and so far have been using it without really understanding how or why it works, which means I'm unable to solve a problem I'm currently facing.

The code I'm working with is below:

```
 @Bean
    public LineMapper<Employee> lineMapper() {
        DefaultLineMapper<Employee> lineMapper = new DefaultLineMapper<Employee>();
        DelimitedLineTokenizer lineTokenizer = new DelimitedLineTokenizer();
        lineTokenizer.setNames(new String[] { "id", "firstName", "lastName" });
        lineTokenizer.setIncludedFields(new int[] { 0, 1, 2 });
        BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Employee> fieldSetMapper = new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Employee>();
        fieldSetMapper.setTargetType(Employee.class);
        lineMapper.setLineTokenizer(lineTokenizer);
        lineMapper.setFieldSetMapper(fieldSetMapper);
        return lineMapper;
    }
```

I'm not entirely clear on what `setNames` or `setIncludedFields` is really doing. I've looked through the docs, but still don't know what's happening under the hood. Why do we need to give names to the lineTokenizer? Why can't it just be told how many columns of data there will be? Is its only purpose so that the `fieldSetMapper` knows which fields to map to which data objects (do they all need to be named the same as the fields in the POJO?)?

I have a new problem where I have CSVs with a large amount of columns (about 25-35) that I need to process. Is there a way to generate the columns in `setNames` programmatically with the variable names of the POJOs, rather than editing them in by hand?

Edit:

An example input file may be something like:

```
test.csv:
field1, field2, field3,
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,j
```

The DTO:

```
public class Test {

    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;

   //setters and getters and constructor
```

Answer (score 3):

I see the confusion, so I will try to clarify how key interfaces work together. A `LineMapper` is responsible for mapping a single line from your input file to an instance of your domain type. The default implementation provided by Spring Batch is the `DefaultLineMapper`, which delegates the work to two collaborators:

- `LineTokenizer`: which takes a String and tokenizes it into a `FieldSet` (which is similar to the `ResultSet` in the JDBC world, where you can get fields by index or name)
- `FieldSetMapper`: which maps the `FieldSet` to an instance of your domain type

So the process is: `String` -> `FieldSet` -> `Object`:

[image]

Each interface comes with a default implementation, but you can provide your own if needed.

#### DelimitedLineTokenizer

The `names` attribute in `DelimitedLineTokenizer` is used to create named fields in the `FieldSet`. This allows you to get a field by name from the `FieldSet` (again, similar to `ResultSet` methods where you can get a field by name). The `includedFields` allows to select a subset of fields from your input file, just like in your use case where you have 25 fields and you only need to extract a subset of fields.

#### BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper

This `FieldSetMapper` implementation expects a type and uses the JavaBean naming conventions for getters/setters to set fields on the target object from the `FieldSet`.

> Is there a way to generate the columns in setNames programmatically with the variable names of the POJOs, rather than editing them in by hand?

This is what the `BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper` will do. If you provide field names in the `FieldSet`, the mapper will call the setter of each field having the same name. The name matching is fuzzy in the sense that it tolerates close matches, here is an excerpt from the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/mapping/BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper.html):

```
Property name matching is "fuzzy" in the sense that it tolerates close matches,
as long as the match is unique. For instance:

* Quantity = quantity (field names can be capitalised)
* ISIN = isin (acronyms can be lower case bean property names, as per Java Beans recommendations)
* DuckPate = duckPate (capitalisation including camel casing)
* ITEM_ID = itemId (capitalisation and replacing word boundary with underscore)
* ORDER.CUSTOMER_ID = order.customerId (nested paths are recursively checked)
```

This mapper is also configurable with a custom `ConversionService` if needed. If this still  does not cover your use case, you need to provide a custom mapper.

Comment: That clears it up quite a bit, the last question that remains is if there is an easier way to get the `FieldSet` names to match the variables of a POJO so I don't have to write out 25 of them by hand. I still am not sure how to do that by modifying the `BeanWrapperSetMapper`

Comment: Please edit your question and add an example of an input file and the target type and what you are expecting. I will edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Edited. Keep in mind again that the reason this is a problem is I will have many different CSVs to support, all with 20-30 fields each. Writing it all by hand would be painful. I suppose one solution is to just create a DTO factory that reads the first line and creates class variables somehow.

Comment: ok thanks. I think what you are looking for is something like: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1772 ? v2 used to have a feature that looks for fields from the header and assign them automatically to the mapper, but this has been removed. Is this what you are looking for?